# In OpenGL, what is a good target for how many vertices in a VBO while maintaining a good frame rate

Tags: c++, opengl

I am working on making a 2D game engine from scratch, mostly for fun. Recently I've been really concerned about the performance of the whole engine. I keep reading articles on a good target number of polygons to try and reach, and I've seen talk in the millions, meanwhile I've only managed to get 40,000 without horrible frame rate drops.

I've tried to use a mapped buffer from the graphics card instead of my own, but that actually gives me worse performance. I've read about techniques like triple buffer rendering, and I can see how it may theoretically speed it up, I cant imagine it speeding my code up into the millions I've read about.

The format I use is 28 Byte vertices, (Three floats for position, 2 floats for texture coordinates, 1 for color, and 1 for which texture buffer to read from). I've thought about trimming this down, but once again it doesn't seem worth it.

Looking through my code almost 98% of the time is spent allocating, filling up, and giving the VAO to the graphics card. So that's currently my only bottleneck.

All the sprites are just 4 sided polygons, and I'm just using GL_QUADS to render the whole object. 40,000 sprites just feels really low. I only have one draw call for them, so I was expecting at least 10 times that from what I've read. I've head some models have nearly 40k polygons in them alone for 3D!

Here is some relevant code to how I render it all:

```cpp
//This is the main render loop, currently it's only called once per frame
    for (int i = 0; i < l_Layers.size(); i++) {
        glUseProgram(l_Layers[i]->getShader().getShaderProgram());

        GLint loc = glGetUniformLocation(l_Layers[i]->getShader().getShaderProgram(), "MVT");
        glUniformMatrix4fv(loc,1, GL_FALSE, mat.data);

        l_Layers[i]->getVertexBuffer().Bind();
        glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, l_Layers[i]->getVertexBuffer().getSize());
        l_Layers[i]->getVertexBuffer().Unbind();
    }
```

```cpp
//These lines of code take up by far the most compute time
void OP::VertexBuffer::startBuffer(int size)
{
    flush();
    Vertices = new Vertex[size * 4];
}

void OP::VertexBuffer::submit(Vertex vertex)
{
    Vertices[Index] = vertex;
    Index++;
}
void Layer::Render() {
    l_VertexBuffer.startBuffer(l_Sprites.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < l_Sprites.size(); i++) {
        Vertex* vert = l_Sprites[i]->getVertexArray();
        l_VertexBuffer.submit(vert[0]);
        l_VertexBuffer.submit(vert[1]);
        l_VertexBuffer.submit(vert[2]);
        l_VertexBuffer.submit(vert[3]);
    }
}
```

I don't know of anything I've been doing wrong, but I just dont understand how people are getting orders of magnitude more polygons on the screen. Especially when they have far more complex models then I have with GL_QUADS.

Comment: I would encourage you to look up AZDO (Approaching Zero Driver Overhead) talks from a few years ago this should get you started. The gist of it is reducing state changes and making fewer (but bigger) draw calls by batching things together.

Comment: "I've only managed to get 40,000 without horrible frame rate drops" Across how many draw-calls?  You generally only get 1000-4000 draw-calls in any given 16 milliseconds.

Comment: @genpfault The program is set up to allow multiple draw calls per frame later on (for multiple shaders), but for now, I only have 1 draw call.

Answer (score 1):

> 98% of the time is spent allocating, filling up, and giving the VAO to the graphics card. So that's currently my only bottleneck.

Creating the VAO and filling it up should actually only happen once and therefore should not affect the frame rate, you should only need to bind the VAO before calling render.

Obviously I can't see all of your code so I may have the wrong idea but it *looks* like you're creating a new vertex array every time Render is called.

It doesn't surprise me that you're spending all of your time in here:

```
//These lines of code take up by far the most compute time
void OP::VertexBuffer::startBuffer(int size)
{
    flush();
    Vertices = new Vertex[size * 4];
}
```

Calling **new** on every render call for a large array is going to considerably impact your performance, you're also spending time assigning to that array every frame.

On top of that you appear to be leaking memory.

Every time you call:

```
Vertices = new Vertex[size * 4];
```

You're failing to free the array that you allocated on the previous call to Render. What you're doing is similar to the example below:

```
foo = new Foo();
foo = new Foo();
```

Memory is allocated to foo in the first call, the first foo created was never deconstructed nor deallocated and there is now no way to do so as foo has been reassigned so the first foo has leaked.

So I think you have a combination of issues going on here.

Comment: You're mostly correct. I do however delete the buffer every frame, so no memory leaks (for now). I wasn't sure how to free up the memory in the buffer each time. So I figured deleting it and making a new one would be faster then just filling it with 0's every call.

Comment: Why do you want to recreate the buffers each frame though?

Comment: Ah, I can just specify how many elements I drew last frame in the draw call. The array creation takes a big chunk of my render time, but still a little over 50% of it still goes into copying the data over to the array, is there any way to help speed that up?

Comment: Sorry if I'm not understanding you but you would speed that up but not recreating your buffers every frame... There is no reason you should have to constantly recreate buffers every time you render. Once you've created your buffers and bound them to the VAO you don't need to anything with it until your done with those buffers e.g. you don't need to render them anymore in which case you simply free them. I suppose the other case would be if they vertices are constantly changing, and you need to recreate the buffer all the time.

Comment: Yeah my vertices change every frame. I might be able to just reuse the same array, but I wasn't sure how opengl would handle getting the same buffer all the time.